# how to extract column&table lineage from flink sql

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I want to build a lineage system for a real-time data warehouse，how can I extract table and column lineage from flink sql?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the [answer](https://www.mail-archive.com/user@flink.apache.org/msg37086.html) in the Flink User Mailing List, I'd like to point out that there is ongoing work in the community to integrate Flink with [Apache Atlas](https://atlas.apache.org/#/). This could be a more viable option for data governance than building your own custom implementation.

You can get some pointers in the [initial discussion](http://apache-flink-mailing-list-archive.1008284.n3.nabble.com/Discussion-Job-generation-submission-hooks-Atlas-integration-tp37298.html).